# Syntax Error using import ctypes

Tags: python

I'm new to  python and have installed Python2.6 
 directory address of python is "C:\Python26"

I tried to use import ctypes

I'm getting below errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\msdecmiolib\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 25
    5DEFAULT_MODE = RTLD_LOCAL
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something's wrong with your Python installation; that line in `ctypes/__init__.py` should simply read

```
DEFAULT_MODE = RTLD_LOCAL
```

It's hard to imagine how that could have happened other than accidentally -- maybe you opened the file to look at it and accidentally hit `5` before saving?  Anyway, you can either fix it yourself and see what happens or if you'd prefer reinstall Python.

(Possibly upgrading to at least 2.7 while you're at it, which would be a good idea unless there's some peculiar reason you can't, although that's up to you.)